# eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class .mainclass

Tags: eclipse, class, load, find, program-entry-point

I am a new user for eclipse.i am user of windows 7.I tried lots of advice not worked.I saw that article and C:Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe(date)how can i fix it?What is your advice

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: Sytem.out.print("hello world"); i just  used standart starting code

Comment: re extract eclipse and check whether you are not using 64-bit PC with 32 Bit JDK

Comment: i am sure.lots of people say that so i check it.can I do in program anything

Comment: becouse there is no connect with program and main.for example in save section or load section etc.what do you thing.also thank you for your comment

Comment: I found the problem when you add your new file eclipse file and if you add your new program in that file eclipse is running.